# In Coq, are there drawbacks in making implicit some arguments?

Tags: coq, implicit-argument

We have

```
eq_ind =
λ (A : Type) (x : A) (P : A → Prop) (f : P x) (a : A) (e : x = a),
  match e in (_ = a0) return (P a0) with
  | erefl _ _ => f
  end
     : ∀ (A : Type) (x : A) (P : A → Prop),
         P x → ∀ a : A, x = a → P a
   
Arguments eq_ind [A]%type_scope x P%function_scope f y e
  (where some original arguments have been renamed)
```

Here only the first argument is implicit. Indeed, in the standard Coq library [Coq.Init.Logic](https://coq.inria.fr/doc/V8.18.0/stdlib/Coq.Init.Logic.html), there is:

> Arguments eq_ind [A] x P _ y _ : rename.

We could make x and y (initially a) implicit and have instead:

> Arguments eq_ind [A] [x] P _ [y] _ : rename.

The advantages seem to me obvious: instead of providing five arguments it would be enough to provide only three arguments. Since the standard library does not make x and y implicit, I thought that there are probably good reasons for that. So, my question is: is there any drawback in making x and y implicit?

More generally, when some arguments can be made implicit because they can be deduced from the other arguments, are there sometimes good reasons to avoid making them implicit?

Comment: It is possible to make Coq set implicit arguments automatically. Check out the [flags starting here in the refman](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/extensions/implicit-arguments.html#mode-for-automatic-declaration-of-implicit-arguments).

I don't know why they are off by default, but my guess would be (new) user-friendliness. [MathComp](https://math-comp.github.io/) has the oposite default.

Answer (score 2):

One potential reason is partial application: if you often want to apply `eq_ind` to all its arguments except the proof of equality (getting something of type `x = y -> P y`), then making `x` and `y` implicit is annoying, because you have to write `@eq_ind _ x P f y` instead of `eq_ind x P f y`, since without the last argument Coq cannot infer `x` or `y`.

Although, in this particular case, I am not sure this is really the reason…